# Need a circular progress bar showing progress on Bar itself and not inside the circle

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress, seekbar

Have a look at the image, I want this kind of progress bar for the android.

All I am getting after lots of search, is the progress bar showing progress inside the circle. But I want to show the progress on Bar itself. Please have a look on image of progress bar I want:

[image]

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to create your own custom view for that kind of component. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: Hi check this out. https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar. Try creating two different size of progress bar inside another.

Comment: hi @Rameshbabu , I want to show progress on Bar itself.

Comment: @EfeBudak Thanks for the reply, But how can I design such kind of progress bar? Any tutorials for this? I am a newbee